# Terraform application gateway Data for certificate is invalid

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I am  deploying a azure application gateway using terraform. In the resource setting, I have this configuration:

```
ssl_certificate {
    data     = filebase64(var.ssl_certificate_path)
    name     = "demo-app-gateway-certificate"
    password = var.ssl_certificate_password
  }

  trusted_root_certificate {
    data = filebase64(var.ssl_certificate_path)
    name = "demo-trusted-root-ca-certificate"
  }
```

The certificate `path` is set as a variable:

```
variable "ssl_certificate_path" {
  default = "./certificate.pfx"
}
```

But when I run terraform `apply` I get the following error:

```
Error: creating/updating Application Gateway: (Name "demo-app-gateway" / Resource Group "XXXX"): network.ApplicationGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="ApplicationGatewayTrustedRootCertificateInvalidData" Message="Data for certificate /subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/demo-app-gateway/trustedRootCertificates/demo-trusted-root-ca-certificate is invalid." Details=[]
```

I tried to use filebase64 and `base64` but I keep getting the same error.

Can please anyone explain me what am I doing wrong here? thank you so much.

Comment: hello @naydenVan, Trusted root certificate needs to be of `.cer` file type not `.pfx ` file type.

Comment: you can refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/certificates-for-backend-authentication#export-trusted-root-certificate-for-v2-sku

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Thank you for your reply. Sorry for this question. The certificate need to be .cert or `.crt` or `cer`?

Comment: it will be  `.cer` file. i.e. X.509(.CER) format.

Comment: Because I tried earlier to add a '.cer'  I get the error `demo-app-gateway-certificate does not have Private Key." Details=[]`

Comment: `demo-app-gateway certificate` is SSL certificate , so it will be of `.pfx` as it requires private key. but `demo-trusted-root-ca-certificate` is Trusted_root certificate , it will be `.cer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Comments , **SSL Certificate** Should be of `.pfx` format as it requires a private key and **Trusted Root Certificate** should be of `.cer` format.

For more information you can refer to Manage Certificate section in this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/certificates-for-backend-authentication).

**So as a solution , you have to use as below:**

```
  ssl_certificate {
    name = "app_listener"
    data     = filebase64("C:/powershellpfx.pfx")
    password = "Password!1234"
  }

  trusted_root_certificate {
    data = filebase64("C:/PowerShellCert.cer")
    name = "demo-trusted-root-ca-certificate"
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]